# copy and overwrite all files

Tags: c#

I have some files that I want to copy to another folder, and overwrite existing files if exist. If in the middle of the copying progress something happened and all the files hadn't been copied completely. How can I be sure, if any file is not copied, none will be copied?

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\myfiles");
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
Foreeach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string temppath = Path.Combine(@"c:\destinationfolder",file.name);
    file.CopyTo(temppath,true);
}
```

Comment: Think you need to store in memory all the old files and check for a unsuccessful `CopyTo()` call where if you get it you copy back the files.

Comment: Do you want to prepare against a crash or only against unsuccessful copying?

Comment: unsuccessful copying but i think crash will couse an unsuccessful copying

Comment: There will always be a problem making this completely correct as long as you are not using a transactional file system ans API. How do you check the copying succeeded and how do you reliably restore the old files?

Comment: Are You saying that there is a transactional file system ans API that can help me or you are saying that it is impossible to be sure about Completely successful copy progress ?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?  Because you will need a _transaction_ to make this happen.

Comment: win7+ and yes I used transaction and it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Erno_de_Weerd Based on your Comment,I found This Nugget Package :

[TxFileManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TxFileManager)

and Based on this Nugget Package I Changed my Code to this and it's Working

```
 public static async Task DirectoryMoveToAsync(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
        {
            // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                    "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                    + sourceDirName);

            }

            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
            // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }

            // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();          


            // Wrap a file copy and a File Delete in the same transaction
            TxFileManager fileMgr = new TxFileManager();
            using (TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope())
            {               
                int x = 0;
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    // Just for the test, what will happen to the files if an exception occurs
                    //*************************************************************
                    x++;
                    if (x == 10)
                    {
                        throw new FileNotFoundException();
                    }
                    //**************************************************************

                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);                 
                    if (fileMgr.FileExists(temppath))
                    {
                        fileMgr.Delete(temppath);
                    }
                    fileMgr.Move(file.FullName, temppath);                
                }

                scope1.Complete();
            }


            // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
            if (copySubDirs)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                   string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                   await DirectoryMoveToAsync(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                }
            }

        }


  private async void ButtonMove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
                await Task.Run(() => DirectoryMoveToAsync(@"Files", @"moved", false)); //"."
                MessageBox.Show("Moved");             
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed : " + ex.Message.ToString() );
            }
            finally
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please note that this implementation on Windows might not be available in future versions of Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/about-transactional-ntfs

Comment: OK my clients haven't any plan to Upgrade to last version of Windows, its working now. for future projects I will find another way to do this.

Answer (score -5):

GetFiles when an exception occurs will stop.  See code below which contains exception handlers to allow you to continue :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WriteFileNamesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```